# Wordpress shortcodes - first shortcode is broken

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, shortcode

I have a page where I'd like to add some concerts to the schedule page.
In order to do so, I decided I will use shortcodes so the user can provide just the necessary data and I will parse it and generate the html in the shortcode function.

First I'd like to tell you why I think this is wordpress related. I have added this code directly to the page php file:

```
<h4>This year hardcoded</h4>
<a href='#' class='p-link'>
    <h2>01.02.2018 / RHCP</h2>
    <p>20:00 / NY</p>
</a>
<a href='#' class='p-link'>
    <h2>03.04.2018 / The Rolling Stones</h2>
    <p>21:00 / LONDON</p>
</a>
<a href='#' class='p-link'>
    <h2>11.12.2018 / Pink Floyd</h2>
    <p>22:00 / TOKIO</p>
</a>
```

And it works fine.

[image]

Since my shortcode function returns the same I expected the same result but I didn't get it. First shortcode result is broken.

This is what I added to the functions.php:

```
function shortcode_issue_func( $atts ) {
    $shortcode_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'date' => '',
        'time' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'location' => '',
        'link' => '#'
    ), $atts );

    $html = "<a href='{$shortcode_atts['link']}' class='p-link'>
                <h2>{$shortcode_atts['date']} / {$shortcode_atts['title']}</h2>
                <p>{$shortcode_atts['time']} / {$shortcode_atts['location']}</p>
            </a>";
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode-issue', 'shortcode_issue_func' );
```

In the wordpress page edit I added this:

```
[shortcode-issue date="19.07.2018" time="20:00" title="RHCP" location="NY" link="http://localhost/wordpress/rep-3/" ]
[shortcode-issue date="21.08.2018" time="21:00" title="The Rolling Stones" location="London" link="http://localhost/wordpress/rep-3/" ]
[shortcode-issue date="23.11.2018" time="22:00" title="Pink Floyd" location="NY" link="http://localhost/wordpress/rep-3/" ]
```

This is the output

[image]

You can notice that sections 1 and 2 are not wrapped together in the "a" tag as section 3 is.

Dumping the $html before return, reveals there should be no issues:

[image]

And the hacky solution I did is to add the empty "p" tag before "a" tag.

```
$html = "<p style='display: none;'></p>
        <a href='{$shortcode_atts['link']}' class='p-link'>
            <h2>{$shortcode_atts['date']} / {$shortcode_atts['title']}</h2>
            <p>{$shortcode_atts['time']} / {$shortcode_atts['location']}</p>
        </a>";
return $html;
```

[image]

But I'd like not to have such hacks in my code and I can't find a reason why this is happening.
I'd be very thankful if somebody can help.

---

Edit 1

The code has the HTML5 declaration --> `<!DOCTYPE html>`

So the "a" tag wrapping should be allowed.

---

Edit 2

I just noticed that there is a "phantom" "p" tag in the resulting html.

[image]

---

Thank you!

Comment: use `<span>` instead of `<p>` , the way you are doing this it's only allowed in `HTML5`  , and if your html document is starting with normal HTML opening , then it will not work the way you are trying , anyway , in both cases , use `<span>` instead of `<p>`

Comment: Tried it with span already and it doesn't work.
and the code has the HTML5 declaration --> "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to *remove the extra spaces* in the `$html` variable value.

So change this:

```
$html = "<a href='{$shortcode_atts['link']}' class='p-link'>
            <h2>{$shortcode_atts['date']} / {$shortcode_atts['title']}</h2>
            <p>{$shortcode_atts['time']} / {$shortcode_atts['location']}</p>
        </a>";
```

..to this one:

```
$html = "<a href='" . esc_url( $shortcode_atts['link'] ) . "' class='p-link'>" .
    "<h2>{$shortcode_atts['date']} / {$shortcode_atts['title']}</h2>" .
    "<p>{$shortcode_atts['time']} / {$shortcode_atts['location']}</p>" .
"</a>";
```

PS: It's always a good practice to `esc_url()` a URL address.

Comment: Thank you @sally-cj for both, the solution and esc_url suggestion.